pyspark.errors.exceptions.base.PySparkRuntimeError: [JAVA_GATEWAY_EXITED] Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
I have downloaded spark (https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) and installed pyspark from pip command. I have also tried nearly all the suggested solutions available online, but the issue still persists and remains unresolved. Could anyone help me on this? I have added all the details in the below:
Spark Version = spark-3.5.3-bin-hadoop3.tgz
Pyspark Scala Version:

.zshrc:

echo $JAVA_HOME:

pyspark is accessible via terminal:

spark_setup.py:



spark init session:
def init_spark_session():
    return SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("sensorForge") \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .config("spark.jars.packages", "file:///Users/perinban/spark/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13-3.5.3,file:///Users/perinban/spark/jars/spark-avro_2.13-3.5.3") \
        .config("spark.executor.extraLibrary", "file:///Users/perinban/spark/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13-3.5.3,file:///Users/perinban/spark/jars/spark-avro_2.13-3.5.3") \
        .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "file:///Users/perinban/spark/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13-3.5.3,file:///Users/perinban/spark/jars/spark-avro_2.13-3.5.3") \
        .getOrCreate()

jar files:

Error while trying to run via airflow:

JAVA_HOME is called correctly in airflow too:


I identified the issue: defining it as python_callable makes the compiler treat it as a Python application instead of a Spark-submit application.
fileMove_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='fileoutbound',
    python_callable=process_files,
    dag=dag
)

For now, I’ve implemented a temporary solution by running it as a separate file through an external subprocess command, using spark-submit like this:
def trigger_spark_job(path, filename):
    try:

        combined_filename = os.path.join(base_path, path, f'{filename}.py')

        # Command to run the Spark job via spark-submit
        subprocess.run([
            "spark-submit",
            combined_filename
        ], check=True)
        print("Spark job triggered successfully.")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error triggering Spark job: {e}")

If anyone has a permanent solution, I’d be open to suggestions & glad to try it out.
